# two Linux kernel modules access one i2c slave device

Tags: linux, module, kernel, i2c

I have 2 Linux kernel modules that both of them need to access the same device through i2c and I am trying to figure out how it is going to work.

The way I see it is that I have come up with anther module/driver to act as a hub to access the device through i2c and export functions to other module/drivers.

If you know better ways to do it, please share. Or pointing to me the existing code for an example.

Thanks

Comment: Can you shed a light on what kind of the device it is? Is it some kind of PMIC or what? (And yes, there are ways how to achieve that properly)

Comment: thanks for replying. The device is a synchronization management unit that includes several DPLL and RTC.

Comment: You have two possibilities (at least): **a)** go with MFD framework, or **b)** instantiate RTC device and clock device from platform code (needs a third driver somewhere, presumable  under *drivers/platform/*).

Comment: thanks for the answer, MFD is perfect for this development